# Why is CUDA unavailable in anaconda environment with pytorch even though its installed successfully, and works in python?

Tags: pytorch, anaconda

I Installed CUDA on my system (windows 10), then also installed pytorch.
I then created an Anaconda environment and installed the same into it as well.
Now my gpu is recognized and is set to available in torch when running through python. and the necessary cuda installation is there within conda environment.

i installed numba and tried getting the info this is what it says:

```
Hardware Information
Machine : AMD64
CPU Name : znver1
CPU Count : 16
Number of accessible CPUs : 16
List of accessible CPUs cores : 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
CFS Restrictions (CPUs worth of runtime) : None

CPU Features : 64bit adx aes avx avx2 bmi bmi2
clflushopt clzero cmov cx16 cx8
f16c fma fsgsbase fxsr lzcnt mmx
movbe mwaitx pclmul popcnt prfchw
rdrnd rdseed sahf sha sse sse2
sse3 sse4.1 sse4.2 sse4a ssse3
xsave xsavec xsaveopt xsaves

Memory Total (MB) : 32720
Memory Available (MB) : 18803

OS Information
Platform Name : Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
Platform Release : 10
OS Name : Windows
OS Version : 10.0.18362
OS Specific Version : 10 10.0.18362 SP0 Multiprocessor Free
Libc Version : ?

Python Information
Python Compiler : MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)
Python Implementation : CPython
Python Version : 3.10.9
Python Locale : en_IN.cp1252

Numba Toolchain Versions
Numba Version : 0.56.4
llvmlite Version : 0.39.1

LLVM Information
LLVM Version : 11.1.0

CUDA Information
CUDA Device Initialized : True
CUDA Driver Version : 11.7
CUDA Runtime Version : 11.7
CUDA NVIDIA Bindings Available : False
CUDA NVIDIA Bindings In Use : False
CUDA Detect Output:
Found 1 CUDA devices
id 0 b'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080' [SUPPORTED]
Compute Capability: 6.1
PCI Device ID: 0
PCI Bus ID: 12
UUID: GPU-446ba761-7d06-bde9-66d7-10b96089d724
Watchdog: Enabled
Compute Mode: WDDM
FP32/FP64 Performance Ratio: 32
Summary:
1/1 devices are supported

CUDA Libraries Test Output:
Finding nvvm from CUDA_HOME
named nvvm64_40_0.dll
trying to open library... ok
Finding cudart from CUDA_HOME
named cudart64_110.dll
trying to open library... ok
Finding cudadevrt from CUDA_HOME
named cudadevrt.lib
ERROR: failed to find cudadevrt:
cudadevrt.lib not found
Finding libdevice from CUDA_HOME
trying to open library... ok

NumPy Information
NumPy Version : 1.23.5
NumPy Supported SIMD features : ('MMX', 'SSE', 'SSE2', 'SSE3', 'SSSE3', 'SSE41', 'POPCNT', 'SSE42', 'AVX', 'F16C', 'FMA3', 'AVX2')
NumPy Supported SIMD dispatch : ('SSSE3', 'SSE41', 'POPCNT', 'SSE42', 'AVX', 'F16C', 'FMA3', 'AVX2', 'AVX512F', 'AVX512CD', 'AVX512_SKX', 'AVX512_CLX', 'AVX512_CNL')
NumPy Supported SIMD baseline : ('SSE', 'SSE2', 'SSE3')
NumPy AVX512_SKX support detected : False

SVML Information
SVML State, config.USING_SVML : True
SVML Library Loaded : True
llvmlite Using SVML Patched LLVM : True
SVML Operational : True

Threading Layer Information
TBB Threading Layer Available : True
+-->TBB imported successfully.
OpenMP Threading Layer Available : True
+-->Vendor: MS
Workqueue Threading Layer Available : True
+-->Workqueue imported successfully.

Numba Environment Variable Information
None found.

Conda Information
Conda Build : 3.24.0
Conda Env : 23.3.1
Conda Platform : win-64
Conda Python Version : 3.10.9.final.0
Conda Root Writable : True
```

i tried doing a clean install of everything on a new virtual server, incase there were some files on my system causing the error, but i still get the same error there as well.

I have done a clean reinstall of CUDA, Python, Conda, and all necessary dependencies on my system as well, but to no avail.

Checked for torch within python and its working. I also ran a tensorflow check as given on the pytorch website and it returned a positive result, showing that its working.

```
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
True
>>> torch.cuda.current_device()
0
>>> torch.cuda.get_device_name()
'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080'
>>>
```

Comment: Because the version of Pytorch you use within the Conda environment and the one you use in the system python are different? And one has built-in support for CUDA and/or the correct libraries and the other doesn’t?

Comment: the error occurs even when I install the correct version of pytorch with appropriate cuda files within the conda environment